# Prove that $Q(x,y)<0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $Q(x,y)= -3x^2 -5y^2 +7xy$
Show that $Q(x,y)<0$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 -\{(0,0)\}$

**My attempt**

It is clear that $Q(0,0)=0$. Also $Q(0,y)<0$ for each $y \neq 0$ and $Q(x,0)<0$ for each $x \neq 0$.

We claim that $Q(x,y)<0$ when $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$.

Suppose that there is a point $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $x_0 \neq 0$ and $y_0 \neq $ where $Q(x_0,y_0)>0$ then:

$7x_0y_0>3x_0 ^2+5y_0^2>0$ so both $x_0$ and $y_0$ must have the same sign.

How could I continue? I'm not sure what else to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$, by AM-GM,
$3x^2+5y^2\geqslant 2\sqrt{15}|xy|>7xy \implies Q(x, y) = -3x^2-5y^2+7xy<0$

Answer (score 0):

Completing the square you can also notice
$$
12\cdot Q(x,y)=-(6x-7y)^2-11y^2
$$
and so $Q(x,y)\leq 0$ with equality when $6x-7y=0$ and $y=0$ (i.e. $x=y=0$).